# seaborn: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have DataFrame **df**:

> ```
> Timestamp-start    datetime64[ns]
> Timestamp-end      datetime64[ns]
> M                          object
> S                          object
> Type                       object
> description_x              object
> description_y              object
> Date               datetime64[ns]
> number_col                 float64
> dtype: object
> ```

**number_col**:

```
51      0.0
0       1.0
1       2.0
2       3.0
52      5.0
      ...  
47    148.0
48    148.0
43    148.0
49    149.0
50    149.0
Name: number_col, Length: 132, dtype: float64
```

And I want to plot histogram using seaborn and column **number_col**

```
>     import seaborn as sns
>     
>     sns.distplot(df, x='number_col')
```

But I got this following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'number_col'
```

I have no idea why this is happening, 'number_col' is already a float column.

Comment: drop the NaNs in number_col

Comment: @darthbaba I don't have NaN's values in that column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`sns.distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) does expect *Series, 1d-array, or list.* as 1st argument, not whole `pandas.DataFrame`, try replacing

```
sns.distplot(df, x='number_col')
```

using

```
sns.distplot(df['number_col'])
```

single column of `pandas.DataFrame` is `pandas.Series` mentioned as *Series* in [`snd.distplot`'s docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html)

Answer (score 2):

I found that [`sns.distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) is deprecated. Instead of that we should use [`sns.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html).

In first argument of [`sns.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) we can put `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
sns.displot(df, x='number_col')
```